# Clustering dataset that evolves with time in Python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I am working on a clustering problem which consists of 13 features, 9 of which change from year-to-year. Having 5 datasets (for the past 5 years) What is the best approach to cluster the yearly observations in order to observe trends or changes in the cluster topology?

Comment: The naive approach would be to recluster your data every year. You can start with one year's data, and if you are satisfied with the cluster centers, you can feed them to the next year's data and see how the data points have moved around them.